# Generating WMS from PostgreSQL table with GeoServer in phpfile?

Tags: geoserver, wms, php

I've a PostgreSQL table build from shapefile. In my phpfile I duplicate this table with a new name.

Now I want to generate a WMS with the content of the new table. The generation must be automatically in code of the phpfile not manually in GeoServer.

Comment: This needs much more explanation. Can you show what you already have? Where does the WMS come from?

Answer (score 1):

The first question to this is why, but passing over that [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org) provides a [REST admin interface](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/rest/index.html) which can be used to add a postgis table as a [datastore](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/rest/api/datastores.html) and create [layers](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/rest/api/layers.html) from that store. There are even [PHP examples](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/rest/examples/php.html) to get you started.